# Dúvida - UML - Casos de Uso

Tags: modelagem, uml, diagrama, casos-de-uso

Olá, gostaria de expressar que os casos de uso “Visualizar Pacientes”, “Agendar Visita” e “Enviar Mensagens” obrigatoriamente precisam da efetuação do login de antemão para poderem ser executadas e realizadas. 
Enfim, eu fiz de duas formas a posição da seta do relacionamento include e gostaria de saber se alguma das imagens está correta ou se há outra maneira de demonstrar esse relacionamento.

[image: Figura 01]

[image: Figura 02]

Comment: A segunda imagem está correta, include aponta pro caso base.

Comment: `efetuar login` o extend aponta pro caso  extendido, faça esta correção, igualmente no `agendar visitar` o extend aponta pro `registrar este do paciente`

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!